# Geocoding API : Connection reset by PEER

Tags: geocoding

We are using Geocoding API in our PROD and DEV GCP environment.
Both the GCP environments have same quota set.

However , with the same number of request** ~200 request per min** , I get success using DEV geocoding API ,
where as the PROD Geocoding API timeouts/error outs with message "ERROR: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer"

Below is the python code :

```
      search_address = df.loc[i, "CompleteAddress"]
        
        parameters = {
        "key" : API_KEY,
        "address" : search_address
        }
        
        base_url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?"
        response = requests.get(base_url, params = parameters).json()
        time.sleep(0.000006)
```

Expecting PROD Geocoding API to run flawlessly like DEV Geocoding API.